# I'm trying to implemenet GUI on some kind of Doubly Linked list

Tags: javafx, linked-list

I've so far done this, it's adding `labels` on the `stage` but removing thing is working but not as intended...
How can I store data of `labels` in an `array` or something so I can compare the `remove.getText();` with that and delete that typed value if previous added as a `label` on `stage`.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    Group root;
    Label label1,label;
    int count=1,count1=1;
public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("LinkedList GUI");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    root = new Group();
    LinkedList<Integer> Linked =new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Button Addfirst = new Button("AddFirst");
    Addfirst.setTranslateX(40);
    Addfirst.setTranslateY(350);
    TextField first=new TextField();
    first.setPrefWidth(60);
    first.setTranslateX(120);
    first.setTranslateY(350);
    Addfirst.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
           int a = Integer.parseInt(first.getText());
           Linked.addFirst(a);
            label1=new Label(" "+first.getText());
                    label1.setFont(Font.font("Buxton Sketch",FontWeight.BOLD,FontPosture.ITALIC,12));
                    label1.setPrefWidth(25);
                    label1.setPrefHeight(25);
                    label1.setTranslateY(60);
                    label1.setTextFill(Color.GREEN );
                    label1.setStyle("-fx-border-color: Blue;");
           root.getChildren().addAll(label1);
            label1.setTranslateX(250-(20*count++));
            count++;
        }
      });
    Button Addlast = new Button("AddLast");
    Addlast.setTranslateX(200);
    Addlast.setTranslateY(350);
    TextField last=new TextField();
    last.setPrefWidth(60);
    last.setTranslateX(270);
    last.setTranslateY(350);
    Addlast.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            int  b= Integer.parseInt(last.getText());
            Linked.addLast(b);
            label=new Label(" "+last.getText());
            label.setFont(Font.font("Buxton Sketch",FontWeight.BOLD,FontPosture.ITALIC,12));
            label.setPrefWidth(25);
            label.setPrefHeight(25);
            label.setTranslateY(60);
            label.setTextFill(Color.GREEN );
            label.setStyle("-fx-border-color: Blue;");
            root.getChildren().add(label);
            label.setTranslateX(250+(20*count1++));
            count1++;
        }
    });
    Button delete = new Button("Delete");
    delete.setTranslateX(350);
    delete.setTranslateY(350);
    TextField remove=new TextField();
    remove.setPrefWidth(60);
    remove.setTranslateX(420);
    remove.setTranslateY(350);
    delete.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            if(remove.getText().equals(first.getText())) {
                Linked.remove(first.getText());
                root.getChildren().remove(label1);
            }
            else if(remove.getText().equals(last.getText())) {
                Linked.remove(last.getText());
                root.getChildren().remove(label);
          }
            else {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setTitle("Error");
                alert.setContentText("Not in List");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        }
    });
    Text text =new Text("Doubly LinkedList GUI");
    text.setStyle("-fx-border-color: Blak;");
    text.setFont(Font.font("Buxton Sketch",FontWeight.BOLD,FontPosture.ITALIC,16));
    text.setTranslateX(150);
    text.setTranslateY(30);
    root.getChildren().addAll(text,Addfirst,first,Addlast,last,delete,remove);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a layout that positions the children for you instead of positioning them yourself. E.g. using a `HBox` as parent for the labels allows you to simply add/remove the child at the same index as the one added/removed in the list:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    HBox container = new HBox(20);
    container.setPrefHeight(40);
    Button addFirst = new Button("add head");
    Button addLast = new Button("add tail");
    Button remove = new Button("remove");
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    HBox buttonContainer = new HBox(10, textField, addFirst, addLast, remove);

    final LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

    addFirst.setOnAction(evt -> {
        String text = textField.getText();
        Integer value = Integer.parseInt(text);
        list.addFirst(value);
        container.getChildren().add(0, new Label(text));
    });

    addLast.setOnAction(evt -> {
        String text = textField.getText();
        Integer value = Integer.parseInt(text);
        list.addLast(value);
        container.getChildren().add(new Label(text));
    });

    remove.setOnAction(evt -> {
        String text = textField.getText();
        int value = Integer.parseInt(text);
        ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.listIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Integer element = iterator.next();
            if (element == value) {
                container.getChildren().remove(iterator.nextIndex() - 1);
                iterator.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    VBox root = new VBox(container, buttonContainer);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Type 10 to the `TextField` and press the `remove` button. It you only consider removing head/tail, this gets even simpler, since the index is `0`/`list.size()-1`

Comment: `Addlast` is working same as `addFirst`. `addLast` should add value in the end.How to do that?

Comment: I just tested my code AGAIN and couldn't find any issue. Are you sure you properly adjusted the code when rewriting it? Otherwise please provide a minimal sequence of operations necessary to reproduce this issue using my code.

Comment: Oh! Sorry @Fabian I just made mistake writing it.